# Eventhandler model change in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to know (in JS) when my model (using knockout.js) or rather a propery has changed.

How do I do that?

Here some code:

```
function DrawingToolViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.drawMode = ko.observable('Line');
}
model = new DrawingToolViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Now the assigned HTML element to drawMode will be updated by the model and back, whatever changes. That's fine, but how can I react in JS if something in the model has changed?

**EDIT**

My question wasn't clear enough, sorry. I know observables but I want to subscribe to ALL properties without doing that for every single property. More like "notify me if something in the model has changed"

Comment: Do you need to know what property was changed? And do you need that to apply to the object deeply, or just the first layer of properties?

Comment: The property doesn't mater and just the first layer, nothing deeply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to register your own subscriptions to be notified of changes to observables, you can call their subscribe function, for example:

```
myViewModel.personName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("The person's new name is " + newValue);
});
```

More details @ [knockoutjs.com](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables)

**Summarizing the comments below**

To get notified on every change in the ViewModel, check [Ryan Niemeyer](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html) article and [John papa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13375/john-papa)'s changeTracker on NuGet

Comment: My question wasn't clear enough, sorry. I know observables but I want to subscribe to ALL properties without doing that for every single property. More like "notify me if something in the model has changed".

Comment: I would take a look at this post then on adding a dirty flag into your knockout. This effectively tracks ANY changes to your view model so you should be able to adapt it to your needs. http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: subscribe may be all you need, if its just a one off subscription. otherwise, a change tracker is more what you need. that post by Ryan is good. Also, I created a changeTracker on NuGet you can check out. I am going to update it with more features combining Ryan's contributions ... soon :)

Comment: I've also coded change trackers not unlike what Ryan and John have done and that does seem to be the way to go. My version accepts an object which specifies which properties to track changes on (the default is all) and is closely related to another bit I wrote that adds totals to arrays (including a notice that any amount in the totals has changed, not just that the total has changed).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified when a specific property changes then there are several ways of doing what you want. One way is to use the `subscribe` function:

```
model.drawMode.subscribe(function(newValue) {    
   // your js goes in here
});
```

**EDIT**

However, if you want to be notified when **ANY** property changes on your view model then I would take a look at this post for creating a 'dirty flag':

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html

This effectively tracks any changes to your view model so you should be able to adapt it to your needs.