# knockoutjs - object's changeTracker/dirtyFlag triggering immediattly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I recently found and applied the [changeTracker/dirtyFlag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995104/eventhandler-model-change-in-knockout-js) approach successfully in my code and everything was good. Very neat and useful. Though, today, I was trying to use it again and something weird was happening: the *somethingHasChanged* trigger was firing as soon as I opened the page.

I looked, searched and nothing. I was not doing any change to the observables after setting the tracker.
After a couple of hours of this, I found the root of the problem:

One of the observables is binded to a `<select>` element thus setting the currently selected `<option>`.

If I remove this binding, it no long triggers.
I don't know why this happens, since the value is only read (supposedly).

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you show your markup and view model?  My guess would be that you are binding against numeric values and the selected one is being written back to your view model as a string, as KO reads it out of the DOM element.

Comment: Your totally correct. Found the answer just now, before reading your comment. :D
Thank you anyway. Would you like to post this comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you are binding against numeric values and the selected one is being written back to your view model as a string, as KO reads it out of the DOM element.